# Exam results processing

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, statistics, statsmodels

I am trying to process around 8000 exam results I have put these in a datatable.

What I would like to know is how you would go about processing this data from a statistical point of view.

I have looked at averages and Max/min using summary in r.
I have used to scatter plot to plot the data.
I have used the ridgeline graph generation in ggplot to get understanding of the density/histogram within the various exam subjects.

I would love to hear if people had processed such data before and what tests they used, any recommendations on plots that I could use to help our users understand the data would also be very helpful

Please send on any links or relevant information or papers that you might feel relevant.

Thanks
P

Answer (score 1):

I have never processed exam results. But in my opinion, you are likely about to perform a multivariate data analysis. The Self-Organizing Map (SOM) can be taken into your consideration. The algorithm provides the topology-preserved surrogacy of data. It is often combined subsequently with clustering algorithms such as K-means, hierarchical clustering, etc. SOM may reveal hidden structure of the data.

[SOM Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map)

[SOM in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/self-organising-maps-for-customer-segmentation-using-r/)